# How To Refresh With Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, refresh, alamofire

I am new to Alamofire, and Swift so please don't get annoyed if my question is dumb.

Right, now that that is out of the way let's get onto the query I have...

I am getting data from a JSON URL and then parsing it with JSON. I am fetching the data using this method ("url" is assigned!)

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
```

Then I am assigned certain parts of the data to UI elements, such as this;

```
self.something.text = json["Something"]["Something"]["Something"][0]["Something"].string
```

This works fine.

I would like some guidance on how to make it refresh, as the data from the URL changes once every 2-5 minutes.

Preferably I would like it to be able to Pull-Up to refresh but anything is fine, refresh button or auto-refresh.

Thank you very much for reading my question, I appreciate any answers/feedback.

If you require me to add some more of my code I will happily do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your Alamofire code in a function
for example

```
func refreshUI() {
    //Alamofire.request........
}
```

then call this function whenever you need to refresh the UI, for example with a timer that calls this function every 5 minutes

i think it's better practice if you write server side code to let your server send remote notifications whenever changes occur

Answer (score 0):

You mention about using pull-up refresh. So i assumed that you are having a `UITableViewController` or `tableView` in `UIViewController`.

Then it is really easy to setup with a `UIRefreshController`. Call this function in your `viewDidLoad`

```
func setupRefreshControl() {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh");
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshIsRequested), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

func refreshIsRequested() {
    //Alamofire.request(.GET, url)... your alamofire request here
    //Upon completion call self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```